# how to prevent MySql Cross Join Query returning zero results if one of the queries returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

I use this query to fetch the ID of the Next and Previous Events in a mysql events table:

```
SELECT e.id AS current, prev.id AS previous, next.id AS next
FROM events e
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT id FROM events 
    WHERE date < '{$result['date']}' 
    ORDER BY date DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) prev
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT id
    FROM events 
    WHERE date > '{$result['date']}' 
    ORDER BY date 
    LIMIT 1
) next
WHERE e.date = '{$result['date']}'
```

This query works fine.

lets pretend the table looks like so:

```
ID | EVENT_NAME   | DATE
------------------------------
1  | test event 1 | 2012-01-01
2  | test event 2 | 2012-01-02
3  | test event 3 | 2012-02-03
```

If i run the query with `$result['date']` as `2012-01-02`, this is returned:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [current] => 2
        [previous] => 1
        [next] => 3
    )
)
```

However if i run the query with `$result['date']` as `2012-01-01` OR `2012-01-03`, an empty result set is returned!

If a previous or a next date does not exist because the passed date is the highest or lowest, I still need the result set to return the next or previous

E.G.

So if i run the query with `$result['date']` as `2012-01-01`, i need the result set:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [current] => 1
        [next] => 2
    )
)

OR

Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [current] => 1
        [previous] => NULL
        [next] => 2
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN with 1=1

```
SELECT e.id AS current, prev.id AS previous, next.id AS next 
FROM events e 
LEFT JOIN  
( 
    SELECT id FROM events  
    WHERE date < '{$result['date']}'  
    ORDER BY date DESC  
    LIMIT 1 
) ON prev 1=1 
LEFT JOIN  
( 
    SELECT id 
    FROM events  
    WHERE date > '{$result['date']}'  
    ORDER BY date  
    LIMIT 1 
) ON next 1=1 
WHERE e.date = '{$result['date']}'
```

Comment: This doesn't work im afraid, Is says syntax error near 'WHERE', i changed it to 'ON', still doesnt work :(

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch table alias comes before ON clause.

Comment: Ive fixed it, it needs to be `) prev ON 1 = 1`, NOT `ON 1 = 1 prev` :)

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch - Ahh.. crap, I knew that.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You might use subqueries:

```
SELECT e.id AS current, 
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM events 
    WHERE date < '{$result['date']}' 
    ORDER BY date DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) AS previous,
(
    SELECT id
    FROM events 
    WHERE date > '{$result['date']}' 
    ORDER BY date 
    LIMIT 1
) AS next
FROM events e
WHERE e.date = '{$result['date']}'
```